Jest encountered an unexpected token when working with React JavaScript
I have created react app with parcel, (New to testing) While doing unit testing for my ContactUs page, I have came across this problem.
Tried few solutions, Which are posted on StackOverFlow but none worked for me.
I am struck here,
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/vishnuvardhan/Desktop/ReactJs/src/components/__tests__/Contact.test.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (8:12):

       6 |
       7 | test("Should load contact us component", () => {
    >  8 |     render(<ContactUs/>)
         |            ^
       9 |     const heading = screen.getAllByRole('heading');
      10 |     expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
      11 | })

This is my package.json
{
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a reactjs working environment for me!",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "test": "jest "
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Reactjs",
    "HTML",
    "CSS"
  ],
  "author": "Vishnu Vardhan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "parcel": "^2.12.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.45",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}

This is my jest.config.js

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};

module.exports = config;

This is my babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
  };

This is my .parcelrc
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.{js,mjs,jsx,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
      "@parcel/transformer-js",
      "@parcel/transformer-react-refresh-wrap"
    ]
  }
}

Any help will be much appreaciated!
